# How to send a payload to Kafka topic reactively, in a very generic way?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

Our code is completely reactive, using Webflux. We want to send messages to Kafka queue and want to do it reactively.

I see there is a spring-cloud-stream-reactive dependency which supports Reactive functionality but for a specific use case where its a data flow.

> Spring Cloud Stream also supports the use of reactive APIs where
>   incoming and outgoing data is handled as continuous data flows.

I understand there exists a way to do it here: https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/

But it looks like tight coupling with kafka specific libs. I like loose coupling here.

Is there a way to do it in a way where my code is not coupled to kafka libs?

Answer (score 5):

So, with spring-cloud-stream 2.x we are gradually deprecating reactive module in favor of [spring-cloud-function](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function) which provides reactive support out of the box. It's a much simpler and certainly less coupling programming model. Here is a bit [more details](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-cloud-stream-fishtown-rc1-2-1-0-rc1-release-announcement).

Basically in the example from the above link all you need is to modify the function itself

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> toUpperCase() {
    return flux -> flux.map(value -> value.toUpperCase());
}
```

Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Function will take care of subscribing, binding etc.
Here is more info on [functional programming model](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function) in Spring Cloud Stream.